# Axios Get Function Returning Pending Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am getting data from an API using Axios within NodeJS. This is my code for that:

```
async function getJobsToPrep() {
    const promise = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: END_POINT + `/opportunities/`,
        headers: {
            "X-SUBDOMAIN": "premier-production",
            "X-AUTH-TOKEN": "******"
        },
        params: {
            view_id: "1000061"
        }
    })
    return promise.data.opportunities
}
```

I've hidden my auth token for security. If I `console.log` the `promise.data` within the function, I get the result I am expecting, but if I try and get the returned data from elsewhere using an async await function like this:

```
console.log(jobsToPrep = async () => await getJobsToPrep())
```

I get this response

```
[AsyncFunction: jobsToPrep]
```

I'm unsure why it is just telling me that `jobsToPrep` is just an async function and not giving me the returned values from the function.

Any ideas much apricated.

Comment: *"I'm unsure why it is just telling me that jobsToPrep is just an async function"* - Because `jobsToPrep` is an `async` function: `async () => await getJobsToPrep()`  You don't appear to be invoking this function or awaiting its result...

Comment: you forgot to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

```
jobsToPrep = async () => await getJobsToPrep()
```

This means "create a function with the text `async () => await getJobsToPrep()` and assign it to the variable `jobsToPrep`". You then log out that function -- not the result of the function, the function as a whole.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
const jobsToPrep = await getJobsToPrep();
console.log(jobsToPrep)
```

Comment: Unfortunately tried this and I'm getting a pending promise as a result

Comment: Ok. Don't quite see how that would happen from the code shown, but the solution should just be to `await` that promise.